# DFT xc integration grid for periodic boundary conditions

Tags: density-functional-theory, exchange-correlation

I am writing my own DFT code using Gaussian basis and now I am writing the periodic boundary conditions (PBC).
What integration grid people usually use for Gaussian basis PBC (+ reference please)?
For isolated molecules, I used the SG3 integration grid with Becke's scheme to combine multi-atomic grids.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Exactly the same grids as for molecules, i.e. Becke grids. You just need to take the periodic boundary conditions into account when building the grid weights.

edit: e.g. PySCF has both molecules and periodic boundary conditions with Gaussian basis sets, and is in my experience a pretty fast code that is also easy to install.

See the pyscf documentation for info. Note: as usual for LCAO programs, PySCF implements PBC in 0, 1, 2, and 3 dimensions.

Comment: Thanks! Is there any paper reference on how to adjust the grid weights for periodic boundary conditions?

Comment: I'm not sure; I think the algorithm is pretty obvious, i.e. you just need to include the periodic copies of your cell in all the necessary dimensions. Then, these weights are the same in every cell.

Comment: @SusiLehtola The links in your answer aare broken. Could you update the links, please?

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue with the links, I'm getting a 404 error "There isn't a GitHub Pages site here." for both. Are they set to be private?

Comment: This may come as a surprise, but links on the internet are not forever. You are commenting on a post that is over two years old, and the links worked at the time of the answer. Here is a fixed link https://gprivate.com/66l3w

Comment: Next time just go ahead and fix the broken links. I would rather spend my time answering new questions than doing busywork with maintaining solved questions.

Comment: Ordinarily I would patch something like that myself, but I didn't know if, for example, you were pointing to that specific fork of PySCF for a reason, which is why I asked.